# Struts 1.1: ActionErrors between different Actions

Tags: java, ajax, struts

I have a form (form.jsp) and a connected FormAction ActionA. ActionA does validations and stores ActionErrors and the form.jsp will print them using `<html:errors../>` tag.
All this is working fine.

I then wanted to add some on-the-fly server side validation on onblur event on one of the form fields (fieldA). I do this using jQuery's `$.post`. It goes to a different Action class (ActionB) which will return a value, that I can print in a div under fieldA. This also works fine.

The problem is to combine the two. I use `saveErrors` method in ActionA and need to reset it with the new errors I get in ActionB.

Example: If fieldA was value "A" and fieldB was "#$" and my ActionA returned errors "No capitals for fieldA" and "No symbols for fieldB" on pressing Submit, then when user changes fieldA to "123" and presses tab, the errors shown should be "No numbers for fieldA" and "No symbols for fieldB" i.e. first error gets removed.

But how do I access the errors, if it isn't in the request!

Comment: It would help if you could add some simplified or pseudo code to assist with the description of what is going on and where it is appearing to break.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I worked it out. I just used jQuery to make the entire div with the error (class="globalError") not show (display:none) and then added my new errors in a similar div under that.. so, it just looks like the errors section changes :-). Thanks for the help.